# Smooth embedding and metric

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Smooth embedding is an immersion which is also a topological embedding.

If we have two metric tensors defined in the two manifolds are the relations between the metrics if there are any?

Also, I would like to know if can we define arbitrary metric tensors on the two manifolds or if are there compatibilities that we need to take into account defining metrics on the two manifolds.

Thanks!

Comment: Which two manifolds do you mean? The manifold you are embedding and its image ?

Comment: There is no general relation between two metric tensors defined on two different manifolds.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis  If smooth embedding is $F: M \rightarrow N$, I am asking about the metrics of $M$ and $N$. Can we define metrics on $M$ and $N$ arbitrarily?

Comment: If the embedding is unrelated to the metrics, as the question suggests by not saying otherwise, then the embedding is immaterial to the question, which amounts to "Is there a relationship between two arbitrary Riemannian metrics on two arbitrary manifolds?"

Comment: I agree with @AndrewD.Hwang. Without explaining how you want the metrics to be related to the embedding, the question does not make sense.